# NSAnimation crash on com.apple.root.default-qos thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, nsopenglview

I'm working on a Cocoa application that leverages NSOpenGLView driven from a CVDisplayLink thread.

We've recently seen a number of crash reports (in the wild) with the following stack trace. 10.11 only.

```
#29. Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos  
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x7fff933bb4dd objc_msgSend + 29  
1  CoreGraphics                  0x7fff9219f19e CGImageGetProperty + 52  
2  QuartzCore                    0x7fff93ae1312 CA::Render::create_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int) + 149  
3  QuartzCore                    0x7fff93ae0fe6 CA::Render::copy_image(CGImage*, CGColorSpace*, unsigned int, double) + 395  
4  QuartzCore                    0x7fff93aeeb6b CA::Render::copy_render_value(void const*, CGColorSpace* (*)()) + 278  
5  AppKit                        0x7fffa010fcec -[_NSCGLSurface _copyNonatomicRenderValue] + 296  
6  QuartzCore                    0x7fff93addc35 -[CALayer(CALayerPrivate) _copyRenderLayer:layerFlags:commitFlags:] + 557  
7  QuartzCore                    0x7fff93add59d CA::Context::commit_layer(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*) + 103  
8  QuartzCore                    0x7fff93add4ca CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 330  
9  QuartzCore                    0x7fff93adba72 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 1766  
10 QuartzCore                    0x7fff93adb0ec CA::Transaction::commit() + 508  
11 AppKit                        0x7fff9f9d95ae -[NSAnimation(NSInternal) _advanceTimeWithDisplayLink:] + 429  
12 AppKit                        0x7fff9f9d92ea -[NSScreenDisplayLink _fire] + 439  
13 CoreFoundation                0x7fffa0b7bb94 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20  
14 CoreFoundation                0x7fffa0b7b823 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1075  
15 CoreFoundation                0x7fffa0b7b37a __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 298  
16 CoreFoundation                0x7fffa0b72871 __CFRunLoopRun + 1841  
17 CoreFoundation                0x7fffa0b71ed8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296  
18 Foundation                    0x7fff98c92ed9 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 270  
19 AppKit                        0x7fff9f93cd72 -[NSAnimation(NSInternal) _runBlocking] + 398  
20 AppKit                        0x7fff9f93cbcb -[NSAnimation(NSInternal) _animationThread] + 66  
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff8e85593d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12  
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff8e84a40b _dispatch_client_callout + 8  
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff8e84e29b _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890  
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x7fff8e84db00 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91  
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff90e4c4de _pthread_wqthread + 1129  
26 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x7fff90e4a341 start_wqthread + 13
```

We have a CVDisplayLink driven thread that is in the following state:

```
#35. CVDisplayLink  
0  libsystem_platform.dylib      0x7fff9214ddbd _OSSpinLockLockSlow + 79  
1  QuartzCore                    0x7fff93ad88af -[CALayer setContents:] + 37  
2  AppKit                        0x7fff9fe302d7 flush_notify + 1169  
3  GLEngine                      0x7fff95e1ecda (Missing)  
4  OpenGL                        0x7fff9180effe CGLFlushDrawable + 66
```

When I set a symbolic breakpoint in `CA::Render::create_image`, I cannot get it to hit in the `com.apple.root.default-qos thread`. So I get first question - when does this stack happen in the QOS thread?  (and not the main thread).

I should note that sometimes the crash happens a bit above (in `CGImageGetProperty`). Any help would be appreciated.